# For Each Loop only running for first variable in a dynamic set

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop, foreach

Thanks in advance for help, I just can't seem to get this working, and I can't figure it out.  I only care about the MONTH and YEAR, not the DAY.  I want to take this data (Col. A,B,C):

```
Data    Min Date    Max Date
a   4/10/1985   10/30/2012
b   4/1/1996    11/1/2010
c   4/1/1997    11/1/2010
d   4/1/1998    11/1/2010
```

and autofill monthly from min to max date in Columns G, and populate the associated data column a through d  in column H like this:

```
(Col.H)  (Col.G)
a   4/10/1985
a   5/10/1985
a   6/10/1985
a   7/10/1985
a   8/10/1985
```

So you monthly autofill all of a, autofill all of b, autofill all of c, and autofill all of d, with the a,b,c,d values preceding it.

My code looks like this now, but it is only autofilling for a, and not for the other 3 data points.

```
Dim Summary As Worksheet
Dim DataCell As Range
Dim DataRange As Range
Dim SummaryLastRow As Range
Dim StartDate As Date
Dim EndDate As Date
Dim NoDays As Integer

Set Summary = Worksheets("Summary")
Set SummaryLastRow = Summary.Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Rows
Set DataRange = Summary.Range(Summary.Range("A2"), Summary.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Rows)

On Error Resume Next
    For Each DataCell In DataRange
        StartDate = DataCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
        EndDate = DataCell.Offset(0, 2).Value
        NoDays = EndDate - StartDate + 1
            If IsEmpty(SummaryLastRow.Offset(1, 0)) Then
            SummaryLastRow.Offset(1, 0) = StartDate
                SummaryLastRow.Offset(1, 0).Resize(NoDays).DataSeries Rowcol:=xlColumns, Type:=xlChronological, Date:= _
                    xlMonth, Step:=1, Stop:=EndDate, Trend:=False
                    Range(SummaryLastRow.Offset(1, 0), SummaryLastRow.Offset(1, 0).End(xlDown)).Offset(0, -1).Value = DataCell
            End If
     Next DataCell
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thank you!

Comment: first remove the `On Error Resume Next` run it again and tell us where is errors.

Comment: FWIW - Why do you include the `.Rows` in statements such as `Set SummaryLastRow = Summary.Range("G" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Rows`?  The `Rows` property of a single cell will just return the single cell that you started with, so it's pointless using it.

Comment: I think the OP should remove those `.Rows` and it should work. Possible issue with SummaryLastRow never move inside the loop. Move the `Set SummaryLastRow = ` line inside the For loop.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that, as soon as you do the first iteration of the loop `SummaryLastRow.Offset(1, 0)` is no longer `Empty`, so the other iterations won't do anything.

You need to put the statement setting `SummaryLastRow` within your loop and, because you **know** that the cell below it will be empty, the `If` statement then becomes pointless.

```
Dim Summary As Worksheet
Dim DataCell As Range
Dim DataRange As Range
Dim SummaryLastRow As Range
Dim StartDate As Date
Dim EndDate As Date
Dim NoDays As Integer

With Worksheets("Summary")
    Set DataRange = .Range("A2", .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

    For Each DataCell In DataRange
        StartDate = DataCell.Offset(0, 1).Value
        EndDate = DataCell.Offset(0, 2).Value
        NoDays = EndDate - StartDate + 1
        Set SummaryLastRow = .Range("G" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)
        SummaryLastRow.Offset(1, 0) = StartDate
        SummaryLastRow.Offset(1, 0).Resize(NoDays).DataSeries Rowcol:=xlColumns, Type:=xlChronological, Date:= _
                  xlMonth, Step:=1, Stop:=EndDate, Trend:=False
        Range(SummaryLastRow.Offset(1, 0), SummaryLastRow.Offset(1, 0).End(xlDown)).Offset(0, -1).Value = DataCell.Value
    Next DataCell
End With
```

Comment: Hey All,  Thank you so much for the help!  I removed the .rows after SummaryLastRow, removed the if statement, then added SummaryLastRow into the For Each, and it worked perfectly.